# How to get a toggled view of the sql results in Oracle Sql Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I had been a user of All round automation pl/sql developer but is now working on sql developer. One thing that used to be very useful was to have a toggled view of the results of any sql statement. This way one is spared of scrolling sideways to view results. Is there anything similar in Oracle sql developer.
Attached are the pl/sql developer views
[image: Normal view]
[image: Toggled or single record view]

Comment: And what exactly is a "toggled view"?

Comment: So a general grid is like
 Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4
Row1 CellVal11 CellVal21 CellVal31 CellVal41
Row2 CellVal12 CellVal22 CellVal32 CellVal42
Row3 CellVal13 CellVal23 CellVal33 CellVal43



in the view I am saying it will display like
Col1 CellVal11
Col2 CellVal21
Col3 CellVal31
Col4 CellVal41


And generally there is a next and previous button to browse through the records

Comment: Please add information by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51963940/edit), not as comments; and as formatted text. (In this instance it *might* be useful to show images from PL/SQL Developer... usually text is preferred over images though.)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click on any row in the result grid you get a contextual menu, and from that you can pick ' Single record view...'

[image]

Which gives you a new dialog showing the single record, with similar navigation controls:

[image]

Another option you might find useful is to right-click on any column heading and change to base the column widths on their content instead of the header text:

[image]

which compresses everything:

[image]

That still scrolls in this case but with fewer columns might eliminate it. You can also fit to window, but that can make things hard to read at all if there are a lot of columns involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexPoole